# mocking custom steps in jenkins vars files

Tags: jenkins, junit, mocking, jenkins-pipeline-unit

In my Jenkins shared library, I have tons of groovy files in the /vars dir that define custom steps.

Many of them have multiple methods defined, and one method in a file may call another in the same file.

I am looking for a way to mock these local methods, so I can unit test each method, specifically those that call the others, without actually invoking them.

Say the structure is like this:

```java
// vars/step.groovy

def method1() {
  def someVar
  
  result = method2(someVar)

  if (result) { 
    echo 'ok' 
  }
  else { 
    echo 'no' 
  }

}

def method2(value) {

  if (value == 1) { 
    return true 
  }
  else { 
    return false 
  }

}
```

Obviously this is a very simplified example. But what I need is a way to mock `method2` so that I can test `method1` with `result` of both `true` and `false`, without actually invoking `method2`.

I have tried the `helper.registerAllowedMethod` pattern, but that doesn't seem to apply to local methods. I've tried Mockito and Spock but they seem like overkill for what I need, and too much change to inject for simple cases.
I've also tried defining the methods locally in the test script with mock closures, but I can't find the right place to do that and/or the correct syntax.

I hope there's a way to do something like this:

```java
// test/com/myOrg/stepTest.groovy
import org.junit.*
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.*
import com.lesfurets.jenkins.unit.BasePipelineTest
import static groovy.test.GroovyAssert.*

class stepTest extends BasePipelineTest {
  def step

  @Before
  void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    step = loadScript("vars/step.groovy")
  }

  @Test
  void method1Test_true () {
    helper.registerAllowedMethod('method2', [], { true }

    result = step.method1()

    assert 'ok' == result
  }

  @Test
  void method1Test_false () {
    helper.registerAllowedMethod('method2', [], { false }

    result = step.method1()

    assert 'no' == result
  }
}
```

UPDATE: one thing i've recently noticed is, in the stacktrace, the `method2` local function is *not* listed. It's as if the local function is instantiated "inline" or in some way that it is not actually a new call, the execution just flows into it. I don't know the technical term. But it explains why the mock of `method2` never gets hit: it is never called.

```java
 method1.call()
      method1.successfullyMockedExternalFunction()
      // i would expect method2 to be here, but it's not - the next stack items are functions _inside_ method2.
      method1.functionInsideMethod2()
```

UPDATE 2:
[This got some attention in the JPU GitHub repo.](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit/issues/461)